# Android Widget don't update correctly

Tags: android, widget

I'm working on Analog Clock Widget which includes a `Textview` to display the date number.
It works but the date (after midnight) doesn't change immediately, it changes minutes or hours after.
My update period is 1000ms.
Please Help.

```
public class Clock_Actions extends AppWidgetProvider{


public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
      RemoteViews updateView = buildUpdate(context);
      appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetIds, updateView);
      super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);
   }

private RemoteViews buildUpdate(Context context) {
      RemoteViews updateView = null;
      Time time = new Time();
      time.setToNow();
      updateView = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.main);
      updateView.setTextViewText(R.id.Date, new Integer(time.monthDay).toString());


      Intent launchIntent = new Intent();
      launchIntent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.android.deskclock", "com.android.deskclock.DeskClock"));
      launchIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
      launchIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
      launchIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED);
      PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, launchIntent, 0);
      updateView.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.analogClock2, intent);

      return updateView;
   }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, due to spec, Android doesn't call the onUpdate less than 1 time every 30 mins so, for this reason, 1000ms doesn't work.

Second, what are you doing it's very very battery intensive, your widget will drain so fast your battery with this refresh time, but to show data, time etc you must use TextClock

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextClock.html

So, instead Data (that I think it's a TextView) you should write

```
<TextClock
android:id="@+id/Data"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:timeZone="GMT+0800"
android:format24Hour="MMM dd, yyyy k:mm"
android:format12Hour="MMM dd, yyyy k:mm" />
```

android:format24Hour and android:format12Hour are related to data format that users use, you can define what do u want see by format

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/DateFormat.html

TextClock doesn't need update from code and it's not battery intensive

Comment: Thanks Iwen I understand the point. But I need to show in the textclock only the date (only the number, ex: for today "28") How I format textclock in xml to show only the day number?

Comment: as doc ... android:format24Hour="dd"
android:format12Hour="dd"

Comment: Perfect. Work great. The only limitation is TextClock is available from API 17. Thanks again.